# What functionality does WebStorm contain which RubyMine does not?

Tags: javascript, ide, ruby

I am looking at buying Rubymine as I am doing a small amount of ruby, but a large amount of html5/javascript.

I was going to get Webstorm as I do have a lot of pure html5/js based frameworks/apps that I am working on, however I then read that WebStorm/PhpStorm/Rubymine etc are all based on their IDEA framework, and made out like each framework contained the functionality of WebStorm anyway, other than a few features which were not there out of the box but could be added through plugins.

The main features that interest me about WebStorm are:

- JS Unit testing from IDE
- JS Lint/Hint coverage within UI
- DOM/JS Refactoring/Intellisense
- Coffeescript support
- SVN/Git integration
- FTP and remote sync (although not as important as the rest)

So given the above, would Rubymine provide the above functionality too? as I would rather have 1 IDE which I can do both in, than having 2 IDEs which have a lot of overlapping functionality.

Is there any specific functionality which is ONLY within Webstorm but not in any of the other IDEs?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tooling (IDEs in this case).  Typically this question belongs on Stack Overflow.  This one is too old to be migrated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

RubyMine has all the features of WebStorm. Note that because of the different release cycles some features may appear first in one IDE, but will be also available in all the other IDEs with the next update. There is no functionality specific to WebStorm that is not available in the other IDEs. See http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5466924?tstart=0

Answer (score 4):

I have the latest version of RubyMine (3.2.4), and while I have only used it for doing strictly Ruby projects, on the right side of the startup page I see that it has bundled plugins for Coffescript, CSS, HTML tools, JS Inspection, JavaScript Debugger etc. so I think you're basically right in assuming that it is essentially WebStorm + Ruby.

However the WebStorm feature page mentions support for Node.JS and JSLint/JSHint, which I do not specifically see in RubyMine.  But [based on this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/editors/javascript_editor.jsp?ide=ruby), I believe you can install these features as additional plugins.

Since you can download [a 30-day free trial of RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/index.html), and [the same for WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/index.html), so you can always download both and compare them.

Comment: See my reply regarding release cycles, RubyMine 4.0 beta is available at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP and has the same features as current WebStorm 3.0 release.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't in sync, and it's very disappointing.

I read something like this saying 'RubyMine' has everything as Webstorm, so I buy it.  Then Webstorm comes out with 6.0 with many new features not in Rubymine.

Then the only answer you get when you ask is 'some' will be made as plugins.

Very vague - no dates, no list of what plugin's, etc... is a confusing guessing game.

So far very disjointed - and no official announcements or details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It'd help if you'd edit your answer to improve the grammar, e.g. use complete sentences. Also, try to answer the question more directly: *What functionality does WebStorm have which RubyMine does not?* Add references where you can. The goal here is to create questions and answers that will be useful not just to the original poster (OP) but also to others who come looking for the same answer, and writing great answers is of course an essential part of that plan.